# Limit the max number of post show in the index page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

you know that by default wordpress shows 10 post in the index page, i need to show 20, where can i modify this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would adjust your theme's Loop to look as follows:

```
<?php 
query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=20');
while(have_posts()) { the_post();
<!-- put your loop code here -->
}
?>
```

This would limit to 20 posts instead of 10.

Comment: He asked how to limit number of posts on the index page, not on all pages.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy to do from your WordPress admin panel.

Go to Settings -> Reading -> and then simply change the number in the box next to the question "Blog pages show at most".

Let me know if that answers your question or not!